# Angular Directive - how to create a dynamic "page-options"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have a div which appears in all the pages of my website.

I want to display it everywhere but with different data according to the current state (I'm using UI router for angular1)

So I decided I should use a directive.

> pageoptions.html

```
<div class="page-options">
    <!-- if state = 'dashboard' -->
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <a ui-sref="restore">Some Action</a>
    <a ui-sref="backup">Another Action</a>

    <!-- if state = 'Edit' -->
    <h1>Edit</h1>
    <a ui-sref="restore">Delete</a>

    <!-- if state = 'settings' -->
    <h1>Settings</h1>
    <a ui-sref="backup">Settings</a>
</div>
```

> pageoptions-directive.js

```
myApp.directive('pageinfo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: "./components/pageinfo/pageinfo.html"
    };
});
```

But I don't know how to insert the logic that I wrote in comments in the HTML.

I would love to get some advice on this

Comment: What do you have in the `pageinfo.html` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to inject the $state service into your directive and use it in your markup to check the current state, using ng-hide or ng-show. Hopefully this gets you pretty close:

```
myApp.directive('pageinfo', ['$state', function($state) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: "./components/pageinfo/pageinfo.html"
        link: function(scope) {
             scope.currentState = $state.current.name;
        }
    };
});
```

template:

```
<div class="page-options">
  <!-- if state = 'dashboard' -->
  <div ng-show="currentState == 'dashboard'">
  <h1>Dashboard</h1>
  <a ui-sref="restore">Some Action</a>
  <a ui-sref="backup">Another Action</a>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="currentState == 'Edit'">
   <!-- if state = 'Edit' -->
   <h1>Edit</h1>
   <a ui-sref="restore">Delete</a>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="currentState == 'settings'">
    <!-- if state = 'settings' -->
    <h1>Settings</h1>
    <a ui-sref="backup">Settings</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: correct answer:) thank you. I already used `link: function(scope, element, attrs){ scope.state = attrs.state; }` which also works fine

Answer (score -1):

maybe this would help:

directive.js:

```
myApp.directive('pageinfo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            state: '='  // if you want take a sting in directive , use '@'
        },
        templateUrl: "./components/pageinfo/pageinfo.html"
    };
});
```

template.html:

```
<div class="page-options">
    <!-- if state = 'dashboard' -->
    <div ng-show="state == 'dashboard'">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <a ui-sref="restore">Some Action</a>
        <a ui-sref="backup">Another Action</a>
    </div>

    <!-- if state = 'Edit' -->
    <div ng-show="state == 'Edit'">
        <h1>Edit</h1>
        <a ui-sref="restore">Delete</a>
    </div>

    <!-- if state = 'settings' -->
    <div ng-show="state == 'settings'">
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <a ui-sref="backup">Settings</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

use directive like this:

```
<pageinfo state="get your state and put it in here"></pageinfo>
```

Comment: For some reason the ng-show always returns false, any idea why? I use exactly your code

Comment: The example shows the `pageinfo` directive being used as an element directive but the code restricts it to use only as an attribute directive.

Comment: What modification do I need to apply to use it as attribute directive?

Comment: ops, my mistake.  just add 'E' in restrict.  answer updated.

Comment: @user3800799 , what is the state value you passed to the  directive?